# Gridview Column Width in ASP.NET 2.0

Tags: asp.net, gridview

How do you control the column width in a gridview control in ASP.NET 2.0?

Comment: Billy,  you should add an "asp.net" tag to your question.  It will get highlight in StackOverflow if those of us interested in those tags (more common).  thanks

Answer (score 8):

You can use the HeaderStyle-Width, ItemStyle-Width or FooterStyle-Width properties.  These can be applied to all the columns or per-column basis.

```
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
        <HeaderStyle Width="10%" />
        <RowStyle Width="10%" />
        <FooterStyle Width="10%" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Name" DataField="LastName" 
                HeaderStyle-Width="10%" ItemStyle-Width="10%"
                FooterStyle-Width="10%" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 3):

I do it using the header style for the column:

```
<asp:BoundField HeaderText="Name" DataField="LastName">
   <HeaderStyle Width="20em" />
</asp:BoundField>
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's the C# code to do it programatically:

```
columnName.ItemStyle.Width = Unit.Percentage(someDouble);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Gridview.Columns[1].ItemStyle.Width = 100;
```

This will set the with in pixel.