# One column in gridview doesn't fix

Tags: asp.net, gridview

My GridView column:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Объекты" SortExpression="objects">
   <ItemTemplate>
   <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("objects") %>' CssClass="ajaxlink"
      NavigateUrl='<%#"objects/" + Eval("i_id") %>'></asp:HyperLink>                    
   </ItemTemplate>
   <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" Width="15%" Wrap="true" />
</asp:TemplateField>
```

It ignored my fixed width! I try put ItemStyle-Width in  tag but it didn't help me. How to fix width in this column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some users have [recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/309815/gridview-column-width-in-asp-net-2-0):

```
<HeaderStyle Width="15%" />
```